# I Added .aar in flutter plugin but how to access .aar classes

Tags: flutter-plugin

I added .aar file in flutter plugin
plugin name -> android -> libs -> myaar

and declared in build.gradle file

dependencies {implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.aar'])}

then in the .aar file have some controllers and classes.Iam unable to get that classes
how to access inside the .aar classes in plugin.java file

Comment: Have you found a solution to this yet?